# PHP readfile() returns 'HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error'

Tags: php, curl, readfile

A have a strange problem. There are some soap api: https://ctaau.vedaxml.com/cta/sys2/business-enquiry-v3-2

It works in browser fine

I've try to

```
readfile('https://ctaau.vedaxml.com/cta/sys2/business-enquiry-v3-2');
```

then I get HTTP/1.1 500.

But curl works fine too:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://ctaau.vedaxml.com/cta/sys2/business-enquiry-v3-2',
));
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo $resp;
```

Questiong: how do you think, I can to get http 200 from that api via readfile()? file_get_contents() returns also 500 error.

p.s: why readfile(), but no SoapClient: as I understand, SoapClient class incapsulates readfile() in it. So, if I get success from readfile(), than I'll try to find a solution for SoapClient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I open https://ctaau.vedaxml.com/cta/sys2/business-enquiry-v3-2 in my browser, it does give me a HTTP 500 error (check the network tab in developer tools).

The result I'm getting is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <soapenv:Fault>
            <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
            <faultstring>Policy Falsified</faultstring>
            <faultactor>https://ctaau.vedaxml.com:8443/cta/sys2/business-enquiry-v3-2</faultactor>
            <detail>
                <l7:policyResult
                    status="Service Not Found.  The request may have been sent to an invalid URL, or intended for an unsupported operation." xmlns:l7="http://www.layer7tech.com/ws/policy/fault"/>
            </detail>
        </soapenv:Fault>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Take a look at the result status message

> Service Not Found.  The request may have been sent to an invalid URL, or intended for an unsupported operation.

Find documentation on the API and find the right service url or find out if you need to authenticate first before using the API.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didnt check it, I think that was a 200 ok. Thanks :)
file_get_contents() and readfile() throws php error, if 500 http error.